# Try-with-resources in Clojure

Tags: clojure, try-with-resources

Does Clojure have an equivalent of Java's [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct?

If not, what is the normal way to handle this idiom in Clojure code?

The pre-Java-7 idiom for safely opening and closing resources is verbose enough that they actually added support for try-with-resources to the language. It seems strange to me that I can't find a macro for this use case in the standard Clojure library.

An example to a mainstream Clojure-based project repository—showing how this issue is handled in practice—would be very helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [with-open](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-open) to bind a resource to a symbol and make sure the resource is closed once the control flow left the block.

The following example is from clojuredocs:

```
(with-open [r (clojure.java.io/input-stream "myfile.txt")] 
  (loop [c (.read r)] 
    (when (not= c -1)
      (print (char c)) 
      (recur (.read r)))))
```

It will be expanded to the following:

```
(let [r (clojure.java.io/input-stream "myfile.txt")] 
  (try
    (loop [c (.read r)] 
      (when (not= c -1)
        (print (char c)) 
        (recur (.read r))))
    (finally (.close r))))
```

As you can see, a `let` block is created with a `try` and `finally` to the call `.close()` method.

Comment: OK, this makes sense. I'd still have to add another `try` form around the `with-open` to catch any exceptions thrown while opening or using the resources—but I guess handling the open/close automation separately from the try/catch logic isn't a bad thing. I was just expecting a 1:1 equivalence with the Java construct—but there's really no reason I should have expected that.

Comment: you can have both a `(catch Exception e ...)` and a `(finally (.close r))` inside a `(try ...)` block but the `with-resource` macro does not support it by default so you will have to write it yourself.

Comment: @DaoWen It is a 1:1 equivalence. `try (Foo x = bar()) {...}` does not handle any exceptions encountered while calling `bar()`. How could it? There is no valid `x` in scope to call `.close()` on.

Comment: @amalloy - My point was that I need both a `try` form and a `with-open`, whereas in Java it's all one construct. The try-with-resources construct *does* catch exceptions thrown in the resource-specification clause—but you're right, it won't try to call `close()` on `x` in your example (there's no point since it failed before `x` was initialized). There's one more subtle semantic difference as well: You get automatic bookkeeping for "suppressed" exceptions when using Java's try-with-resources.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something more close to java, making up some macro on top of `with-open`. It could look like this:

```
(defmacro with-open+ [[var-name resource & clauses] & body]
  (if (seq clauses)
    `(try (with-open [~var-name ~resource] ~@body)
          ~@clauses)
    `(with-open [~var-name ~resource] ~@body)))
```

so you can pass additional clauses alongside the binding.

```
(with-open+ [x 111]
  (println "body"))
```

expands to simple `with-open`:

```
(let*
  [x 111]
  (try (do (println "body")) (finally (. x clojure.core/close))))
```

while additional clauses lead to wrapping the it in try-catch:

```
(with-open+ [x 111
             (catch RuntimeException ex (println ex))
             (finally (println "finally!"))]
  (println "body"))
```

expands to

```
(try
  (let*
    [x 111]
    (try (do (println "body")) (finally (. x clojure.core/close))))
  (catch RuntimeException ex (println ex))
  (finally (println "finally!")))
```

But still it is quite an opinionated solution.